# Python Pandas Compare 2+ Columns & Select Different Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around this one.

I could either process it as multiple data frames (df1, df2, df3, etc.) or multiple columns in one dataframe.

The data would be formatted essentially as:

A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2

or

df_a["column_1","column_2"]
...
etc.

The formula would need to iterate through every row & select the "1" (A1, B1, C1) with the highest number from the *previous* row and select the corresponding lettered column (e.g. if B1[i-1] was the highest, select the value in B2 and transpose it to a new column ("D") - or to a new df.

```
for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    result = ### select column A,B,C2 based on  max value in A,B,C1[i-1] ###
    df_results.append(result)
```

Any tips on approach would be appreciated.

Comment: From reading what you wrote I think it’s possible to do in one data frame multiple columns. But post some sample input output so we can help you with the code

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I solved it by using a intermediary dataframe for each row on the main dataframe and flipping the axis - then sorting - and taking the top row and appending it to a final dataframe.

It is messy, but I think it is working. Will finish before updating.